# Can I create something like a macro in Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers, automation

I have this long formula that is used in a lot of columns:

```
=SE(N17<60; DEF.NÚM.DEC(SOMA(60; −N17); 1); "✔︎ Aprovado")
```

So, when I need to change something in this formula, I need to edit each one of then. So to avoid this kind of duplication, can I create something like a macro, which will make me able to do something like that:

```
def myMacro($POS):
  return SE($POS<60; DEF.NÚM.DEC(SOMA(60; −$POS); 1); "✔︎ Aprovado")
```

And use it like:

```
=myMacro(N17)
```

---

<sup>Note: The formulas are in portuguese.</sup>

Comment: Numbers does not have a built in macro system that can do as you've explicitly asked in your question.

Comment: The answers you received so far are not going to be able to do as you've explicitly asked but you might be able to apply automation/scripting to help you modify your existing document or insert a formula into a given cell or range via a keyboard shortcut or selecting a custom service/quick action or custom script from a menu. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

There is rich documentation and deep automation support for Numbers being automated with Automator and AppleScript. Here is a mid-tutorial link to where to save your scripts and shows the menu bar to trigger these scripts.

I could see you entering the formula or substituting / selecting the range for which to apply a function quite easily.

- https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/script-menu.html

The nice thing about that site is that it has many tutorials as well to cover the scripting syntax / how to use the script editor and all the things you learn in Numbers are general to other apps that have scripting support on macOS - first party apps and third party apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can using Applescript. A similar question is [answered here](https://macmost.com/forum/how-do-i-record-a-macro-like-excel-in-mac-numbers.html). This site includes a link to a video showing how to create a macro using Applescript.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but If anyone’s still interested in a possible solution, there is a way to get macro-like behavior.  I don’t know if this feature is documented.

To do this you need to create a two column table with the first column frozen.

Column A would be your “macro” name (e.g. “Default Name”).  Column b would be its value.

If you entered `=def` then one of the auto completion options should be “Default Name”.  It’s treated like a function and it would give you the value in column b.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]